# How can I duplicate the category page in a custom module?

Tags: magento2

Originally I was trying to copy over all of the xml from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` into my own xml file. This route was not working.

So I have now changed to where I am extending my controller from `\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View`.

```
<?php
namespace My\Custom\Controller\ProductGrid;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Design;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;


/**
 * Class HeaderA
 * @package My\Custom\Controller\Header
 */
class ProductGridA extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View
{
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return parent::execute();
    }
}
```

And then inside my xml file I have

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="catalog_category_view"/>
    <body>

    </body>
</page>
```

My page is loading, but the content is coming out blank. I believe I need to set a category to be pulled up somehow but I can not figure out the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Controller of your module has to extend Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View

Also, instead of copypasting layout file use handle update and use references to change parameters of blocks.

Comment: Ah okay, so what would I make the handle update be in this case? catalog_category_view?

Comment: I think I got it close, but I am getting a 404 error on the view now.

Comment: @Metropolis do you have frontend router set up?

Comment: Yes, its working fine, until I change the controller parent. I basically just created a blank class that is extending from `\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View`. I basically want it to reuse the constructor and the execute function from the parent I would assume. So I think that may be why I am getting the 404. I may need to do something more inside the execute function of the child.

Comment: @Metropolis that's propably the case since execute method of Category View controller is checking request for parameter and checks if it points to correct category - if not then it redirects to 404.

Comment: So if I extend the execute function in my class, what would I need to pass it to get this working properly? I guess it would need a category like womens or something? Technically I just need any category right now for testing purposes. This is really just to be able to make frontend templates.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: @Metropolis you have to dig into this yourself, my guess is that the category is needed for collection and some additional data in block/templates (eg. category name in header) so now you either create a category with data you need and pass correct parameters to the controller or do bigger overhaul with new blocks and templates.

Comment: @Metropolis Did you get the solution? can u please share how you did that?